# Column to be filled based on condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following data

```
PROD_NO    PROD_CAT     PROD_DESCRIPTION
X23        PENS          N/A
X23        PENCIL        in warehouse
X23        INK           "
X30        BOOKS         "
X30        DRAWINGS      not in warehouse
X30        ERASERS       "
```

What I would like to achieve is if PROD_DESCRIPTION is having N/A or ", then I would like those rows to be filled with comments exist
for that prod_no. e.g. for `X23` **in warehouse** to be filled for all rows.  For `X30` **not in warehouse** to be filled for all rows.

```
PROD_NO    PROD_CAT     PROD_DESCRIPTION
X23        PENS          in warehouse
X23        PENCIL        in warehouse
X23        INK           in warehouse
X30        BOOKS         not in warehouse
X30        DRAWINGS      not in warehouse
X30        ERASERS       not in warehouse
```

How can I do this?
There are many prod_no and prod_description varies for each prod_no

Comment: Sample data is great, can you add expected result too?

Comment: @jarlh I have included expected output. Thanks

Comment: Great. What's the expected result if a prod_no has both 'in warehouse' and 'not in warehouse'?

Comment: @jarlh There are many prod_no and prod_description varies for each prod_no

Comment: @jarlh Idea is fill description with value exist for each prod_no.

Comment: I understand, that's why I'm asking what to do if a prod_no has two different PROD_DESCRIPTION values, both 'in warehouse' and 'not in warehouse', which one should I chose?

Comment: @jarlh In that case any one of them. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a JOIN table with MAXIMUM PROD_DESCRIPTION for each PROD_NO and then use DECODE to output this value for NULL,'' or 'N/A':

```
SELECT T.PROD_NO,
       T.PROD_CAT,
       DECODE (T.PROD_DESCRIPTION, NULL,TMAX.PROD_DESC_MAX, 
                                     '',TMAX.PROD_DESC_MAX,
                                  'N/A',TMAX.PROD_DESC_MAX,
                                        T.PROD_DESCRIPTION) 
       PROD_DESCRIPTION
FROM T
LEFT JOIN (SELECT PROD_NO, 
                  MAX(PROD_DESCRIPTION) PROD_DESC_MAX
            FROM T GROUP BY PROD_NO) TMAX
     ON T.PROD_NO = TMAX.PROD_NO
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2434d/4)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Try this and let me know

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE SET 
 PROD_DESCRIPTION=decode(PROD_NO,'X23','in warehouse','X30','not in warehouse')
 WHERE PROD_DESCRIPTION='N/A' or PROD_DESCRIPTION=''
```

**OR**

This should also work.

```
 UPDATE YOUR_TABLE SET 
     PROD_DESCRIPTION= 
        CASE WHEN PROD_NO='X23' THEN 'in warehouse'
        WHEN PROD_NO='X30' THEN 'not in warehouse'
        END
     WHERE PROD_DESCRIPTION IN('N/A','')
```

**Edited**

Assuming there are only two types of description for all production no. Pass all prod_no in `IN()` accordingly.

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE SET 
     PROD_DESCRIPTION= 
        CASE WHEN PROD_NO in('X23','X25',... so on) THEN 'in warehouse'
        WHEN PROD_NO in('X30','X31',.... so on) THEN 'not in warehouse'
        END
     WHERE PROD_DESCRIPTION IN('N/A','')
```

Comment: There are many prod_no and prod_description varies for each prod_no

Comment: what is a table name, which has prod_no and prod_description ?

Comment: All exist in one table.

Comment: No. my question is, which prod_description belongs to which prod_no ? How would I/database know ? You are telling each prod_no has its own description. right ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select prod_no
     , prod_cat 
     , case when prod_no = 'X23' 
       then 'in warehouse' 
       else 'not in warehouse' end as prod_description 
from [your_table_name]
```

Comment: There are many prod_no and prod_description varies for each prod_no

Comment: You should handle all possible values in case statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE [YourTable]
SET PROD_DESCRIPTION = 
( CASE  
WHEN (PROD_DESCRIPTION = N/A and PROD_NO = X23) THEN 'in warehouse' 
WHEN (PROD_DESCRIPTION = "" and PROD_NO = X23) THEN 'in warehouse' 
WHEN (PROD_DESCRIPTION = N/A and PROD_NO = X30) THEN 'not in warehouse' 
WHEN (PROD_DESCRIPTION = "" and PROD_NO = X30) THEN 'not in warehouse' 
ELSE  (PROD_DESCRIPTION)
END )
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT` using a correlated sub-query:

```
select t1.PROD_NO,
       t1.PROD_CAT     
       (select max(t2.PROD_DESCRIPTION)
        from tablename t2
        where t2.PROD_NO = t1.PROD_NO
          and t2.PROD_DESCRIPTION <> 'N/A'
          and t2.PROD_DESCRIPTION <> ''),
from tablename t1
```

`JOIN` version, with a `GROUP BY` to find 'not in warehouse' or 'in warehouse':

```
select t1.PROD_NO,
       t1.PROD_CAT,
       t2.PROD_DESCRIPTION
from tablename t1
LEFT JOIN (select PROD_NO, max(PROD_DESCRIPTION)
           from tablename
           where PROD_DESCRIPTION <> 'N/A'
             and PROD_DESCRIPTION <> ''
           group by PROD_NO) t2
    ON t1.PROD_NO = t2.PROD_NO
```

If a prod_no has both 'in warehouse' and 'not in warehouse', the `MAX` will return 'not in warehouse' as value. If you want 'in warehouse' instead, switch to `min(t2.PROD_DESCRIPTION)` in the sub-select.

Comment: For some reason column which are having " is not getting filled with description .

Comment: Replace IS NULL with = '', and IS NOT NULL with <> ''.

Answer (score 1):

I Think This Will Help :)

```
SELECT P.PROD_NO,P.PROD_CAT,(SELECT PROD_DESCRIPTION FROM PRODUCT WHERE
PROD_DESCRIPTION NOT IN ('"','N/A') AND  PROD_NO = P.PROD_NO limit 1 ) 
AS DESCRIPTION  FROM PRODUCT P
```

I have use Inner query because i think that there may be more then one description for single product which is not  '"' OR 'N/A' " IF It is not the case then you can use this

```
 SELECT P.PROD_NO,P.PROD_CAT, P1.PROD_DESCRIPTION FROM PRODUCT P
 JOIN PRODUCT P1 ON P.PROD_NO = P1.PROD_NO 
 WHERE P1.PROD_DESCRIPTION NOT IN ('"','N/A')
```